# How to install Monit on Centos 6.2

Tags: monit

I have a server running on Centos 6.2 , I want to install monit in it , please help me to install monit step by step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not a good fit for this site. If you get stuck on a particular step please update your question. From cursory [search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=Installing+monit+on+centos&oq=Installing+monit+on+centos&gs_l=serp.3..0.24968.27614.0.27798.9.7.0.2.2.0.171.648.5j2.7.0...0.0.iOFMgluEQIY) that are plenty of guides on how to do this.

Comment: Agreed, you can simply search online for multiple guides such as http://www.howtoforge.com/server-monitoring-with-munin-and-monit-on-centos-5.2-p2

Answer (score 2):

Monit is available via the [Repoforge/RPMForge repository](http://repoforge.org/use/). It's a single package with no real dependencies, so you can either download it separately, or as part of a configured repo. If you enable the repo, installation is simply `yum install monit`. If you just want the lone package:

- Go to [the Monit package page](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/16391008/dir/redhat_el_6/com/monit-5.2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html).
- Select a mirror, for instance: [ftp.pbone.net](ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/monit-5.2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm)
- You can also download the package to your system using:

`wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/monit-5.2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm`

or even install directly with:

`rpm -ivh ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/monit-5.2.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm`

- Profit!

(of course, then you'll actually need to configure Monit... That take a bit more work, but the [helpful setup examples](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) and [detailed documentation](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) will be good resources.)